# не создается база MSSQL

Tags: sql, inno-setup

```
[Files]
Source: 
Source: "C:\projects\Atechnology.installer.v3\Database_backup\dealer.bak"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: srv
Source: "C:\projects\Atechnology.installer.v3\Database_backup\dealer.bak"; DestDir: "{app}\Base\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Components: srv


[Run]
Filename: "{pf64}\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"; Description: "Развертывание базы ABC"; Parameters: "-U sa -P 123123 -S localhost -d master -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE dealer FROM DISK='{app}\Base\dealer.bak' WITH MOVE 'ecad' TO '{app}/Base/dealer.mdf', MOVE 'ecad_log' TO '{app}/Base/dealer_log.ldf', REPLACE; exec sp_configure 'clr enabled',1; RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;"" "; StatusMsg: "Развертывание базы ABC..."; Components: srv
```

Хочу понять, почему не разворачивается база из бэкапа, SQL 2016 устанавливается верно, проверял. Заранее благодарю за помощь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ниже приведу картинку, при ресторе базы какие-то ссылки на файлы на них происходят ошибки

Answer (score 1):

В секции [Run] вместо localhost нужно написать полное имя SQL сервера, база создалась